# InvMillsRatio & Heckit correction

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, regression

I am currently writing my thesis and relatively new to R. 
I need to perform a heckit two stage model (invMillsRatio plus heckit) since I have so much missing data. However I have no clue how to do that. I have 3 main models (2 linear regressions (one lm and one log-linear) and 1 censor regression), but how can I now perform this heckman correction?

I would really appreciate your help a lot, i have absolutely no idea at all!

Comment: I typed "heckman missing values R package" into a search engine and got some potentially useful looking links (`sampleSelection` package was the first hit). Maybe start there and run through the examples.

Comment: I think you'll get more helpful comments about this question over on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks, i already tried that for  a very long time. However as i wrote above, i only have simple lm regression, and no probit or logit regression as necessary for the Heckman correction. now i was just wondering if i can still perform it or if there's a way around or sth similar

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of your earlier post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561126/invmillsratio-heckit ..... can you explain how this is different?

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled for a while with the same problem, and I think I have found a solution. It is certainly not the most elegant way to proceed, but it runs fine. Additional feedback and friendly suggestions will always be welcome!

**First step:** create a dummy out of your dependent variable. My dependent variable was FDI outstock, so it took the value of 1 if it was different from 0 or NA, and 0 otherwise. Here is the code I used to create a new column for my dummy DV:

```
outstock <- outstock %>%
  mutate(
    outstock4 = as.numeric(
      case_when(
        log_outstock == 0 ~ "0",
        is.na(log_outstock) ~ "0",
        log_outstock > 0 ~ "1",
        log_outstock < 0 ~ "1",
        TRUE ~ as.character(log_outstock)
      )
    )
  )
```

**Second step (if applicable to your dataset):** declare as panel data, using the plm.data() function from the plm package. I used this code:

```
outstock4 <- outstock %>%
    plm.data(index = c("CP", "year"))
```

**Third step:** In the sampleSelection package, the heckit function works as this:

```
heckit(dummy_DV ~ IV,
      DV ~ IV, data)
```

Note that it is 2 separate regressions (first your selection equation, then your estimation regression equation), and that there is no mention of lm, glm, log-linear or whatever.

Now, for me, this works as long as I do not have fixed effects to include. In that case, the high number of NAs makes it impossible to run. Therefore I removed the NAs, not using na.omit() because that would remove too many observations, since I do not use all of the variables present in the database in each model) but rather filtering them out as such:

```
model1 <- summary(heckit(dummy_DV ~ IV,
               DV ~ IV + as.factor(year) + as.factor(iso_o) + as.factor(iso_d), 
               data = filter(database, !is.na(IV1), !is.na(IV2), !is.na(IV3), !is.na(IV4), !is.na(IV5))))
```

I hope it helps. Good luck!